# How to check input from HTML form and print ERROR message on the spot using JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function validate(){
u=document.CustomerLogin.UserName.value;
p=document.CustomerLogin.Password.value;
rp=document.CustomerLogin.RePassword.value;

if (u==""){
 document.write("Enter a unique username");
 return false;
 }
if (p!=rp){
 document.write("Retype Password Incorrect");
 return false;
 }
return true;
}
</script>
```

The messages are printed on separate page but i want them to be printed at the same place in front of text box! Please help. Thanks!

Comment: it's not 'writing to a separate page' but rather you over-write the entire contents of your DOM when you use the 'document.write' statement. Use innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use Document write, it's hazardous...

document.getElementById("anidofanElementinthePage").innerHTML = " string to add by javascript";

```
<script>
function validate(){
u=document.CustomerLogin.UserName.value;
p=document.CustomerLogin.Password.value;
rp=document.CustomerLogin.RePassword.value;

if (u==""){
  document.getElementById("theIdOfyourTextBlocInForm").innerHTML = "Enter a unique username";
 return false;
 }
if (p!=rp){
 document.getElementById("theIdOfyourTextBlocInForm").innerHTML = "Retype Password Incorrect";
 return false;
 }
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! 

And how to print these messages in front of text boxes now ?

Comment: Please the flag the answer.  just do like that : <p id="errorlogin"></p> <input type="text" />   and in javascript : document.getElementById("errorlogin").innerHTML = "Retype Password Incorrect";

Answer (score 0):

you would need to detect text change. One way is to use this:

```
<input name="blah" onchange="validate()" ... />
```

**EDIT**
To add text on the same page, include the script using `<script src=...>` and then add `<div id='validation[i]'></div>` next to each of the inputs where `[i]` is increased by 1 each time (so validation1 validation2 so on). Then, use `getElementById('validation[i]').innerHtml` to change the value.

Comment: No! I know that already. onchange will work even without SUBMIT click but it also redirects to another page to print error! I want the error on same page. I want this -->For example: 

Pass: 123
Retype Password: 321 **Error:[Password mismatched]**

Answer (score 0):

document.write will simply append the message to the end of the page. The simplest solution would be change it to an alert like this:

```
if (u==""){
 alert("Enter a unique username");
 return false;
}
```

Otherwise you will need to create new DOM elements(either before hand or when an error is detected) to hold the message and position them next to the inputs

Comment: Actually after the page has finished loading `document.write` will overwrite the contents of the page.